# Success Factors Status history of a Job Application

Tags: sap-successfactors

I'm extracting data from SAP Success Factors via OData API.

And I need the status history of a JobApplication entity, i.e. how and when the application's status had been changed.

Unfortunately I can not find any documentation about it and it looks like I can not extract this data.

Do you know if there is such information and how I can extract it?

My second option is to extract the data from the Integration Centre. Does it provide such information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Entity AuditTrail.
In your case entity **JobApplicationStatusAuditTrail**

[image]

Comment: furthermore als JobApplicationAudit - entity should also fulfill the request, but the one above is more specific.

Comment: Thanks @zYrEx,
This is perfect !